# How can I show the button contents on top of rectangle?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-canvas

[image]

```
    Button(
      onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
      colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
        containerColor = Color(0xFF282828),
        contentColor = Color.White
      ),
      modifier = Modifier
        .height(50.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .drawWithContent {
          val w = size.width
          val h = size.height
          drawContent()
          clipRect(right = w * progress.value) {
            drawRoundRect(
              color = Color(0xFF634EFB).apply { this.copy(alpha = 0.38F) },
              cornerRadius = CornerRadius(x = 100.dp.toPx(), 100.dp.toPx()),
              size = Size(width = w, height = h),
              topLeft = Offset(0f, 0f),
            )
          }
        }
    ) {
      Text(text = "Hello")
    }
```

The rectangle will be changed based on the progress value .

As of now the button is getting overlapped due to the rectangle . I have tried giving zIndex to text and changing the alpha value of rectangle, But it's not working .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply a different [`blendMode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BlendMode) in the `drawRoundRect` method:

```
.drawWithContent {
    val w = size.width
    val h = size.height
    drawContent()
    clipRect(right = w * progress.value) {
        drawRoundRect(
            color = Color(0xFF634EFB).apply { this.copy(alpha = 0.38F) },
            cornerRadius = CornerRadius(x = 100.dp.toPx(), 100.dp.toPx()),
            size = Size(width = w, height = h),
            topLeft = Offset(0f, 0f),
            blendMode = BlendMode.Plus
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, `Blend.overlay` works but the colour gets a little bit changed . Any other solutions that can be applied to persist the colour ?

Comment: @Techjd In the linked doc there are the different options for blendMode. Choose the best option for you.

Comment: I saw the docs , all of them are changing the colours in some way, Any other solution you would like to suggest ?

Comment: @Techjd a good solution can be BlendMode.Plus. Check the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `progress.value` is a known, dynamic value, so you can use it to set the width of a rectangle.

Update your `drawWithContent` section with something like this:

```
.drawWithContent {
    val width = size.width
    val height = size.height

    drawRect(
        color = Color(0xFF634EFB).copy(alpha = 0.38F),
        size = Size(width * progress.value, height)
    )
    drawContent()
}
```